# GridLayout works in background well but not showing on real device

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gridlayout

The problem is the elements (TextViews) in GridLayout are shown well in emulator but on real device they are not shown directly and only after pause the Mainactivity they appear. Also while they are not shown they still work peobebly in background and the proccess of the activity still work as if they were showing up.
I've generated GridLayout in Java file, not in xml

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found that problem is in xml file. In this case I have made some change in elements on layout xml file and the problem was fixed.